# Creating IF statement that if "Variable" != NULL then WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to have a query that will let me select ALL from the table if the variable is null, and my only option here is PURE MYSQL
here is my CODE

```
SELECT *
FROM tblPersonalData
if(VARIABLE!=null,WHERE    Studno=VARIABLE},'all')
```

Comment: select all from database or table?

Comment: select all from table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple `OR` operation:

```
select
*
from tblPersonalData
where variable is null
or studNo = variable;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can emulate this behavior with the logical `or` operator. Note, however, that `null` is not a value, and you should test it explicitly with the `is` or `is not` operators, not `=` or `!=`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tblPersonalData
WHERE  variable IS NULL OR sutdno = variable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblPersonalData
WHERE Studno = COALESCE(VARIABLE, Studno)
```